# Specifying MongoDBObject as content of $set

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I need to construct an update query like this:

```
{
  $set: {"yow": 1, "man": 2},
  $setOnInsert: {"a": 3},
}
```

I just don't know how to do it using Cashbah. The thing is the value for the $set, I got it from a JSON String (which I parsed into MongoDBObject). So I have a code like this:

```
val setVal = JSON.parse(jsonString).asInstanceOf[MongoDBObject]
val updateQuery = $set(...) ++ $setOnInsert("a" -> 3)
```

I don't know what to put in the "...". I tried:

```
val updateQuery = $set(setVal) ++ $setOnInsert("a" -> 3)
```

But I got a compilation error that says:

```
type mismatch;  found: com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject  required: (String, ?)
```

I also tried:

```
val updateQuery = $set(setVal.toSeq) ++ $setOnInsert("a" -> 3)
```

Got similar error:

```
type mismatch;  found: Seq[(String, AnyRef)]  required: (String, ?)
```

tried with toMap, same thing.

Thanks in advance for your help!,
Raka

Answer (score 2):

Very close [`$set`](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/#com.mongodb.casbah.query.dsl.SetOp) takes varargs of fields `(String, A)*` so this will work:

```
$set(setVal.toSeq: _*) ++ $setOnInsert("a" -> 3)
```

Alternatively, you could opt out the dsl for the `$set` part:

```
MongoDBObject("$set" -> setVal) ++ $setOnInsert("a" -> 3)
```